# Get ZSys to manage computer

Tags: zfs

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 root on ZFS following the instructions provided by [OpenZFS Ubuntu 18.04 Root on ZFS](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2018.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html).

I have now upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and installed ZSys but its not managing rpool.

```
root@ubuntuzfs:/# zsysctl machine list
ID                 ZSys   Last Used
--                 ----   ---------
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu  false  current

root@ubuntuzfs:/# zsysctl state save -s
ERROR couldn't save system state: Current machine isn't Zsys, nothing to create
```

Does anyone know how to get ZSys to manage this computer?

Comment: I suspect you need to do a clean install of 20.04 for zsys to manage the pool.

Comment: I have with 20.04 the same issue after system repair from a crash. Any way to fix it? Even if i'll do a fresh install. When I restore my files. It is going to come back.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like adding the property com.ubuntu.zsys:bootfs with value yes for the dataset containing the /-filesystem solves the problem:

```
# zfs set com.ubuntu.zsys:bootfs=yes $(df --output=source -t zfs / | tail -1)
```

In a bash this sets the property com.ubuntu.zsys:bootfs of the dataset to yes.
For example:

```
# zfs list -o name,com.ubuntu.zsys:bootfs $(df --output=source -t zfs / | tail -1)
NAME                      COM.UBUNTU.ZSYS:BOOTFS
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_82yzok  yes
```

Restart zsys-services:

```
# systemctl restart zsys*
```

After this is set the zsysctl is running:

```
# zsysctl list
ID                        ZSys  Last Used
--                        ----  ---------
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_82yzok  true  current

# zsysctl save --system
ZSys is adding automatic system snapshot to GRUB menu
```